# LibGDX: ShapeRenderer drawing... nothing

Tags: libgdx

So drawing a shape should be really easy, right? Well, the following draws exactly nothing.

...why?

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

camera.update();
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
shapeRenderer.rect(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 50, 50);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: And how does your camera get setup? and what's WIDTH and HEIGHT?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your camera is properly initialized.

For Example:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(); //Put this in init
camera.setToOrtho(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
```