# ShapeRenderer not drawing new lines added during runtime

Tags: java, android, libgdx

**TL;DR My ShapeRenderer will render lines, but only sometimes.**

I've seen these posts: [LibGDX: ShapeRenderer drawing... nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062348/libgdx-shaperenderer-drawing-nothing), [Libgdx NESTED ShapeRenderer not drawing lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798600/libgdx-nested-shaperenderer-not-drawing-lines), and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800505/libgdx-shaperenderer-not-drawing-in-loop. I'm having the same issue, but none of them have answers. I'm hoping someone can spot what I am doing wrong

I have two classes, an ApplicationListener **A** and GestureListener **B**. In ApplicationListener A, I have a global `ArrayList<StarPair> pairs` which I instantiate in the `create()` method of **A**. **A** also has an instantiated `ShapeRenderer draw`. In my render loop, I have the following code:

```
// Render lines
cam.update();
draw.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
draw.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
draw.setColor(Color.GREEN);
for(StarPair pair : pairs)
    draw.line(pair.v1, pair.v2);
draw.end();
```

Which works fine when I just put random star pair objects into the list from within the `create()` method.

My desired behavior is to have the list to start empty and to have the `touchDown()` event from **B** add a `StarPair` object to the pairs list, which is then rendered by the `draw`.

In `touchDown()` I create a dummy `StarPair newPair` and add it to `pairs` with: `gazer.pairs.add(newPair);`, where gazer is the instance of **A** that has the ShapeRenderer `draw`. I can see this being added to `pairs` when I debug and put a conditional breakpoint within `render()` that only hits after a breakpoint on `gazer.pairs.add(newPair);` The list grows from size 0 to size 1. The coordinates in v1 and v2 are as I expect them to be, but a new line never starts rendering on my screen, despite their being a StarPair in the list.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I don't think the List or rendering code is wrong. Could you show us the code where you add the new Pair? Are you sure that the coordninates are definitely within the viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newPair` object that I was adding to the end of the list was being set to `new StarPair()` on every call to `touchDown`, but it was declared as a global variable, so the `pairs` list in my `ApplicationListener` was getting a reference to an object that was immediately being cleared - hence no line drawing. Making `newPair` local to `touchDown()` solved the issue.

**TL;DR My mistake, not libGDX**